# Using CMake in Qt: location ui_*.h is not recognized by Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, auto-generate, uic

I tried to use *Qt Creator* to manage User Interface files `*.ui`:

`mainwindow.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.hpp"

#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent)
    : QMainWindow{parent}
    , ui{new Ui::MainWindow}
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{ ; }
```

`mainwindow.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QScopedPointer>

namespace Ui {

class MainWindow;

}

class MainWindow
        : public QMainWindow
{

    Q_OBJECT

public :

    explicit MainWindow(QWidget * parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~MainWindow();

private :

    QScopedPointer< Ui::MainWindow > ui;

    Q_DISABLE_COPY(MainWindow)

};
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project("gui" LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt5 CONFIG REQUIRED Core Widgets)

set(UI_FILES "mainwindow.ui")

set(SOURCES)
list(APPEND SOURCES "main.cpp")
list(APPEND SOURCES "mainwindow.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OS_BUNDLE} ${SOURCES} ${UI_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS YES
    )
```

When I put cursor on `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"` filename and push <kbd>F2</kbd>, then I get the following error message:

[image: error messagbox]

I have investigated the problem: it origins from different locations, mentioned in file `D:/Projects/build/proj/Debug/src/gui/CMakeFiles/gui.dir/CXX.includecache`:

```
gui_autogen/include/ui_mainwindow.h
D:/Projects/proj/gui/gui_autogen/include/ui_mainwindow.h
```

These are two consecutive lines, which the only contains `ui_mainwindow.h` as substring in whole the file. Second line contains wrong location, even if I add `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/gui_autogen/include")` to `CMakeLists.txt`, then `cmake` either way can't generate right cache file.

What is workaround to this? I think I can edit (patch) some `*.cmake` files in *Qt* subsystem of *CMake* distribution. I almost sure this is closely related to `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` directive and other stuff.

#### ADDITIONAL:

Main problem is that I can't create slot from form editor's *Go to slot* context menu item to autogenerate slot from *Qt Cretator*.

Comment: But is a file `ui_mainwindow.h` generated somewhere?

Comment: @piwi Yes, look my next comment. Project builds fine.

Comment: In-source workaround is to prepend file name with relative path: `#include "gui_autogen/include/ui_mainwindow.h"`. But it looks ugly, because of implementation details.

Comment: When you call `target_include_directories()`, what is `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}`? Didn't you mean `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`?

Comment: @piwi `message(FATAL_ERROR "---${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}---")` gives `---D:/Projects/build/proj/Debug/src/gui---`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the workaround. It is a *Qt Creator*'s parser limitation: pointer to `Ui::MainWindow` should be a plain old raw pointer. That is I cannot use any RAII-wrapper, like `std::unique_ptr` or `QScopedPointer` and should manually `delete` `Ui::MainWindow` instance at destruction time. Maybe sometimes it will be fixed at least for `QScopedPointer`. I hope.